# addSbtPlugin without scala version

Tags: maven, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am trying to use the babel webjar plugin in my project that is built with playframework 2.5, which basically runs `sbt` to build the project.

When I put

```
addSbtPlugin("org.webjars" %% "babel" % "6.3.26-1" )
```

in project/plugins.sbt, I get this error:

```
[info] Resolving org.webjars#babel;6.3.26-1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.webjars#babel;6.3.26-1
<trying other repositories>
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/babel_2.10_0.13/6.3.26-1/babel-6.3.26-1.pom
```

The pom file is located at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/babel/6.3.26-1/babel-6.3.26-1.pom.  This is almost the address that sbt tried, but sbt added the scala version.

Is there a way to tell sbt to not add the scala version?  I tried this version and a single percent sign, and both of them added the scala version.

I am using sbt 0.13.9.

Comment: Remove the erroneous extra `%`

Comment: I tried with one % and two %.  I think I saw something about needing to delete a plugins directory after make a change like this elsewhere: does that sound familiar to you?

Comment: Nothing of the sort is ever necessary.